# MySQL 5.6 procedure pass Workbench's validator but doesn't work, Error Code: 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

That code is passing the MySQL Workbench validator but isn't working at all. Can somebody help me to figure out?

All it does is throw this error after an execution failure.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

```
drop procedure if exists dividir_tabla_por_usuario;

delimiter //
create procedure dividir_tabla_por_usuario(tabla varchar(100), columna_usuario varchar(100), columna_fecha varchar(100))
begin
  set @i = 0;
  set @q1 = concat('select count(*) from (select distinct ', columna_usuario ,' from ', tabla , ' order by ', columna_usuario ,' asc) as t1 into @c');
  prepare p1 from @q;
  execute p1;
while @i <= @c do
  set @r = 0;
  set @q2 = concat('select * from ', tabla , ' where ', columna_usuario ,' = (select ', columna_usuario ,' from (select @r:=@r +1 as ord, ', columna_usuario ,' from (select distinct ', columna_usuario ,' from ', tabla , ' order by ', columna_usuario ,' asc) as t2) as t3 where ord = ', @i ,' ) order by ', columna_fecha ,' asc limit 30000'); 
  prepare p2 from @q2;
  execute p2;
  set @i := @i + 1;
end while;
end//
delimiter ;

call dividir_tabla_por_usuario('mytable', 'mycolumn1', 'mycolumn2');
```

I appreciate your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```sql
...
/* prepare p1 from @q; */
PREPARE p1 FROM @q1;
...
```